# New Relic Spring AOP Documentation

Tags: newrelic

I am looking for a sample implementation of new relic custom events via Spring AOP in Spring Boot or Spring platform. Appreciate if anyone can share any documentation on this. I would like to monitor some of the specific metrics data via New Relic which I believe New Relic AOP module be the best suit for.